# search api returns empty list using drf haystack for elastic search

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, drf-haystack

I have following models,

```
class ProductKeyword(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name="products")
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

and search index,

```
class ProductKeyWordIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):

    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    name = indexes.CharField(model_attr="name")
    product = indexes.CharField(model_attr="product")

    autocomplete = indexes.EdgeNgramField()

    @staticmethod
    def prepare_autocomplete(obj):
        return " ".join((
            obj.name, obj.product
        ))

    def get_model(self):
        return ProductKeyword

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(
            date_created__lte=timezone.now()
        )
```

and the viewset,

```
class ProductKeywordSearchView(HaystackViewSet):
index_models = [ProductKeyword]

serializer_class = ProductKeywordSerializer
```

and the url configuration,

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'prod_key', ProductKeywordSearchView, base_name="prod-key-
search")


# The API URLs are now determined automatically by the router.
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls))
]
```

and the settings.py (haystack configuration)

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 
'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://localhost:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'bhkhata',
        'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True,
        'TIMEOUT': 300,
    },
}
```

**i saved data through django shell, and checked that the data are successfully saved in the `ProductKeyword` model.**

trying to get result using following search api,

```
 http://localhost:8090/api/hs/prod_key/?name=sayaabintel
```

but its returning a empty list with 200 status.

i am new in elastic search, so not sure what causing this above api to return a **empty list**, there could be one possibility that the object i am trying to search, not been indexed in elastic search, so i have applied the following management commands of elastic search to build index,

```
python manage.py update_index
```

but still the api returning a empty list

then i tried the following,

```
python manage.py rebuild_index
```

still returning a empty list

and then

```
python manage.py clear_index
```

not working yet, returning a empty list

so what i am missing here? i have followed the following drf-haystack documentation,

[drf haystack documentation](http://drf-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/stable/01_intro.html)

in mention, i am using

```
elastic search( version 5.4.0)
elastic search-dsl( version 5.3.0)
```